Identify a drama(?) with a blind man/woman regaining sight at end
I remember watching this film when I was younger and really not liking it, because it was too serious and the idea of it scared me. But it has always been an annoyance to me that I can't remember what it was.
The movie involved someone who was blind. They were an older girl/boy or younger man/woman. I really can't remember. At the end they had some sort of operation and I remember them having big pads over their eyes. Then, their sight returned when the pads were taken off. Some part of me thinks there might have been a plane ride or something similar (hot air balloon?) towards the end, perhaps as a celebration, although it's a bit hazy.
The movie was in English. I'm fairly certain it was in colour. I watched it when I was younger, which would have been early to mid 1990s, so I imagine it was probably created in mid to late 80s. I remember absolutely nothing about the film before the ending I described.
Unfortunately, that's all I have to go on!

Can you recall any other details about the story line?

Not really. I don't remember if the person was happy/sad or anything. I think it was a woman. I'm aware this is next to nothing to go on, so really just hoping it triggers something in someone!

Could be Seven Pounds, but that wasn't from early to mid 90s

@invalid_id: Definitely not. No Will Smith and a much older "feel" to it.

I also thought it was seven pounds

Definitely far too recent. It was from when I was a child. I was born in 1987, so I imagine it was from mid to late 1990s at the latest, and quite possibly before it. My overall date range estimate would be 1980s - mid 1990s.

Possibly "Blink" (1994), with Madeline Stowe? Regains sight more towards the beginning, not at the end, though.

@JohnP: I've so little memory it's difficult to say, but I speed-watched it last night and there are definitely some very familiar looking scenes. I'm happy going with that if you want to add it as an answer.

A possibility is "Blink", a 1994 murder thriller with Madeline Stowe. In it, a musician that has been blind for 20 years regains her sight through a new operation. Part of the recovery is that she sees things in flashes, and is unsure if they are real or not. 
This leads to her being pursued by someone that she may have seen in the act of murder.

I ask you to answer this then promptly go ahead and forget all about it. So sorry! It's been a while, but I think this is the film. My memory was very hazy, but the trailer and scenes from my quick flick through of it seem to match. Thank you!

Was it "At First Sight" with Val Kilmer?
http://www.fandango.com/atfirstsight_v174351/plotsummary

I'm late responding but no, definitely not.
